# Smooks, java to java transformation

Tags: transformation, smooks

I have a situation , where i am trying to convert 5 different javaobject to 1 single java source.

Can this be done using Smooks ? if yes  how? I went throught their examples, but it looks like it can convert only 1 source javabean to another target javabean.

I trying to have multiple sources of javabean to 1 target javabean.

Any help ??

Comment: Smooks appears to be a tool for transforming structured data.   Are you trying to transform java source code, which I doubt is in that category?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of aggregation with Smooks, but should be possible to transform all your objects within java collection, e.g. list. Will this work for you?